# Load external script in angular.json's script array from web

Tags: javascript, angular-cli

In the angular.json file we have the section "scripts" (projects -> architect -> scripts)
In this array I try to load some scripts. The first script works fine, but the https scripts don't. **They are available when I directly open the links in the browser, they also load when I add them at the end of my index.html as `<script src="https://...>`, but somehow it doesn't work in the scripts array:**

```
"scripts": [
          "node_modules/@webcomponents/custom-elements/src/native-shim.js",
          "https://my-server.com/polyfills.js",
          "https://my-server.com/polyfill-webcomp-es5.js",
          "https://my-server.com/polyfill-webcomp.js",
          "https://my-server.com/scripts.js",
          "https://my-server.com/main.js"
        ]
```

**Further info:**

The problem is that when I add them in the index.html as  tags, I get an error that I don't get when I add the local files in the script array. I don't know what the difference is between adding the scripts in index.html or in angular.json, maybe the order in which the scripts load? Anyway I can't add the scripts locally, I have to load them from the extern server at runtime (I only added them locally for testing, but in production mode I need to load them from the server)

When I add the files locally and load them in the scripts array it works perfectly fine:

```
"scripts": [
          "node_modules/@webcomponents/custom-elements/src/native-shim.js",
          "src/scripts.js",
          "src/polyfills.js",
          "src/polyfill-webcomp.js",
          "src/polyfill-webcomp-es5.js",
          "src/main.js",
        ]
```

Comment: I found this in the Angular docs about the angular.json scripts array, so I would expect the https scripts to load EXACTLY as if they were defined in index.html: "scripts: An object containing JavaScript script files to add to the global context of the project. The scripts are loaded exactly as if you had added them in a <script> tag inside index.html. See more in Styles and scripts configuration below." (https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config)